# problema al instalar fmw_12.2.1.3.0_wls.jar

Tags: java, linux, weblogic

buenas tardes estoy instalando el fmw_12.2.1.3.0_wls.jar en un servidor linux pero me marca el siguiente error

tengo la version de java "1.8.0_301"

```
java -version 
java version "1.8.0_301" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_301-b09) 
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.301-b09, mixed mode)
```

````
Preparing to launch the Oracle Universal Installer from /tmp/OraInstall2022-07-12_02-05-31PM
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/jdk1.8.0_301/jre/lib/amd64/libawt_xawt.so: libXtst.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1934)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1817)
        at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:810)
        at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1934)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1838)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:871)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
        at java.awt.Toolkit$3.run(Toolkit.java:1636)
        at java.awt.Toolkit$3.run(Toolkit.java:1634)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.awt.Toolkit.loadLibraries(Toolkit.java:1633)
        at java.awt.Toolkit.<clinit>(Toolkit.java:1670)
        at java.awt.Component.<clinit>(Component.java:593)
        at oracle.sysman.oio.oioc.OiocOneClickInstaller.main(OiocOneClickInstaller.java:643)```
````

Comment: Qué versión de JDK tienes? Por favor ve a [edit] la pregunta y añade la salida de `java -version` en tu servidor linux (o indica la versión que está usando ese weblogic, si es diferente a la que tiene por defecto el OS).

Comment: tengo la version java -version
java version "1.8.0_301"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_301-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.301-b09, mixed mode)

Comment: Instala `libxtst6` y/o `libxtst6:i386` en tu linux. La sintaxis exacta depende de la distribución. [Esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17355863/cant-find-install-libxtst-so-6) tiene respuestas que te pueden servir